# Javascript: on div click expand div height, and on second click collapse div height?

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following javascript that adjusts my div height when a user clicks `trend_exp_bt`.

It works fine at the moment. However, if the user clicks `trend_exp_bt` again, i want to reset the div height (130px).

Please can someone show me how to do this, i've tried to look at toggle function on google but these don't seem to be working for me.

```
<script>
    $('.trend_exp_bt').click(function(){
    $('.trending_contain').animate({height:'500'})
    $('.trend_exp_bt').css("line-height", "30px");
    $('.trend_exp_bt').html("&and;");

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use click handlers, you will have to remove the "expand" handler and add a "collapse" handler after it is expanded. You will have to do the opposite when a user collapses the div element.

```
function expandDiv() {
    $('.trending_contain').animate({height:'500'});
    $('.trend_exp_bt').css("line-height", "30px");
    $('.trend_exp_bt').html("&and;");
    $('.trend_exp_bt').off('click').on('click', collapseDiv)
}

function collapseDiv() {
    $('.trending_contain').animate({height:'200'});
    $('.trend_exp_bt').css("line-height", "30px");
    $('.trend_exp_bt').html("&or;");
    $('.trend_exp_bt').off('click').on('click', expandDiv)
}

$('.trend_exp_bt').click(expandDiv);
```

Comment: perfect. this suits my requirements better since it allows me to facilitate changing my html elements. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe toggling a class would work for you?

```js
document.getElementById('trend_exp_bt').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('exp-panel').classList.toggle('expanded')
}
```

```css
.panel {
  width: 250px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.expanded {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<button id="trend_exp_bt">Expand</button>
<div id="exp-panel" class="panel">
</div>
```